# Search folder, copy to new folder and change names of the files!

Tags: macos, bash, script, file-transfer

So I'm trying to recursively search folder, and as you might imagine it will be the "Photos"-folder in MacOS.

And in the process, I would like to change the file name, why you might ask? Because Nextcloud is for some reason changing the image name to `year-month-day hour-minute-second $(increment number)`. So I need to be able to define this starting increment number.

This is what I have so far:

```
# Lets say that starting increment number should be I=7398
# name="$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S' "$file").$(ls "$file"|cut -d . -f2)"
# echo $name
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -size +500k -exec sh -c '
    for file in "$@"; do
        folder="/path/to/backup/folder/$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%Y/%m' "$file")"
        echo mkdir -p "$folder"
        echo cp "$file" "$folder"
    done
' sh {} +
```

This works perfect! But I would like to in the process change the name from the files EXIF data, to be `'%y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S {increment number}'.ext`, `18-08-15 18-32-29 3453.JPG` or whatever it is. Is this possible?

This above script reads a JPG, creates directory of the year the file image was created, created another folder corresponding to the month, copies the file to that year folder.

Expected result: also change name `'%y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S {increment number}'.ext`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, where should/could I get that data from if not the EXIF?

Comment: Thanks but not helpful. Example: I have file names DSC_0001.JPG up, it was snapped 2018-01-22 at 13:00:22, I want to move that file to folder `~/backup/2018/01` and rename it to `2018-01-22 13-00-22.JPG $(increment)`. (in this example it is one file, but I have around 30k?

Comment: Thats what Im trying to figure out

Comment: Adam, I've updated my answer, so you should have a second look as the changes made are better than the original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a *proof of concept* to show how I'd build out the *target_directory* and *target_filename* from the *source_filename*, based on information in your OP and comments:

```
$ ls -1
DSC_0008.JPG
DSC_0034.JPG
DSC_0077.JPG
DSC_0132.JPG
codetest

$ cat codetest
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -size +500k -exec sh -c '
i=7398
for f in "$@"; do
    m="$(exiftool -d "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S" -FileModifyDate -s -S "$f")"
    d="/path/to/backup/directory/${m:0:4}/${m:5:+2}"
    echo mkdir -p "$d"
    echo cp "$f" "$d/$m $i.${f##*.}"
    ((i++))
done
' sh {} +

$ ./codetest
mkdir -p /path/to/backup/directory/2018/11
cp ./DSC_0008.JPG /path/to/backup/directory/2018/11/2018-11-26 15-39-09 7398.JPG
mkdir -p /path/to/backup/directory/2018/12
cp ./DSC_0034.JPG /path/to/backup/directory/2018/12/2018-12-26 11-52-30 7399.JPG
mkdir -p /path/to/backup/directory/2019/03
cp ./DSC_0077.JPG /path/to/backup/directory/2019/03/2019-03-02 08-36-07 7400.JPG
mkdir -p /path/to/backup/directory/2019/04
cp ./DSC_0132.JPG /path/to/backup/directory/2019/04/2019-04-03 23-42-36 7401.JPG
$
```

Obviously with the `echo` *command* in place, the *output* shown is not quoted and would fail if that was the actual *command* executed while copying; however, with the `echo` *command* removed, the actual executed *command* has quotes around the *arguments* and would not fail because of the spaces in the *target_filenames*.

---

**Using `stat` instead of `exiftool`:**

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -size +500k -exec sh -c '
i=7398
for f in "$@"; do
    m="$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S" "$f")"
    d="/path/to/backup/directory/${m:0:4}/${m:5:+2}"
    echo mkdir -p "$d"
    echo cp "$f" "$d/$m $i.${f##*.}"
    ((i++))
done
' sh {} +
```

---

**Note:** Both of these worked when run as either a *script*, or, sans the *shebang*, copied and pasted into **Terminal**. That said, I'm not sure I'd run this on 30K files all at once without adding some *error handling* as appropriate for what this *code* will do. I'll leave that up to you to decide how, or if, you want to implement any *error handling* in the example *code* shown.

Comment: Looking good! I get the expected result, thanks for your time and effort

Comment: Two suggestions: for `m` - `exiftool -d '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S' -FileModifyDate -s -S FILE` and for `d` - `exiftool -d '%Y/%m' -FileModifyDate -s -S FILE`. Now the challenge, this could all be written in `exiftool`.

Comment: @fd0, Thanks, I incorporated `exiftool -d "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S" -FileModifyDate -s -S "$f"` into `m="$(...)"` but did not use `exiftool` for `d`, as I did not want to call `exiftool` a second time. Instead, I chose to replace `$(tr '-' '/' <<<"${m:0:7}")` with `${m:0:4}/${m:5:+2}`, which eliminated the use of `tr`, and _parameter expansion_ of an already existing _variable_ is much faster and less overhead then calling `exiftool` a second time. As to, "Now the challenge, this could all be written in `exiftool`", that would be very interesting; however, I'll leave that up to you to do. 

Comment: @nohillside, Thanks for your input, it at least made me find an alternate solution using `exiftool` without `awk`; however, I've incorporated part of the suggestion made by fd0, which was better then my original and subsequent `exiftool` usage. I also got rid of what really was an unnecessary call to `tr` as well, with a rewrite of the whole answer too.